# Reverse for 'staff_info_update' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/staff/info/edit/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: django

I want to update additional information of staff class from update view of user class, where staff class has one to one relation with user class. These are my codes
models

```
class StaffInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='staff_information', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views

```
class StaffUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = StaffEditForm
    template_name = 'forms/staff_edit_form.html'
    context_object_name = 'staff'
```

templates

```
  <a href="{% url 'staff_info_update' staff.staff_information.pk %}"> Additional Information </a>
```

url

```
path('admin/staff/info/edit/<int:pk>/', StaffAddInfoUpdateView.as_view(), name='staff_info_update'),
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message means your staff.staff_information.pk is empty in the {% url ... %}

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have no `StaffInfo` record in database. You can either update on an existing record using `UpdateView`, or create a new record using `CreateView`

Create a `SfaffInfo` instance in your `/admin` page linking to the user, then updating page will not show the error